# IEnumerable<> instead of List<> goes well when reading objects

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Consider my following class Album:

```
public class Album
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public DateTime Registered { get; set; }
}
```

I have no troubles retrieving data out and populating my album and my photo collection.

However now I also want to 'Add' a Photo item into my Photos collection, 'Add' is not recognized as a valid method on Photos.

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'does not contain a
>   definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first
>   argument of type....

What should I do as a simple thing to get it to work with IEnumerable? I don't want to change my property to

```
public List<Photo> Photos { get; set;}
```

Do I really need to implement ICollection on my Album class?

```
 public class Album : ICollection<Photo> { ... }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you dont just use 'List<Photo>' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making Photos a private List then create a standard property exposing it as an IEnumerable. Then add an "AddPhoto" method to your album object.

This way you allow album to control how it adds items to its internal collection.

```
public class Album
{
    private List<Photo> _photos = new List<Photo>();

    public IEnumerable<Photo> Photos { get { return _photos; } }

    public void AddPhoto(Photo photo)
    {
        _photos.Add(photo);
    }
}
```

*Edit This is a similar answer to dasblinkenlight, just with a more fleshed out code. I'll leave it here for now as it adds a little bit of clarification.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to change the property type to something that allows addition (`IList<Photo>` or `ICollection<Photo>`) add a separate method for adding pictures, like this:

```
public void AddPhoto(Photo p) {
    ...
}
```

This would let you keep `IEnumerable<Photo>` as the type of your property, and also allow for validation of what the callers put in. For example, your code would be able to detect if a photo is too big or too small, and throw an exception. This would be a lot harder to do if you exposed `IList<Photo>`, because you would need to provide your own implementation that overrides `Add`.

You should also make the setter of your auto property private, or replace the auto property with a getter + a backing field.

Comment: +1 deffo the way to go. Would probably need to remove the setter for the `Photos` property.

Comment: I read that using IEnumerable would make my LINQ perform lot faster. Would that change if I use another collection interface?

Comment: @codingjoe IEnumerable has nothing to do with making your Linq perform faster. What matters is the underlying collection type (since Linq performs some optimisations for certain types such as `List<T>`). It's likely to be *faster* if you change the underlying type to `List<T>`.

Comment: @codingjoe I think they meant something else: when you use `IEnumerable` without calling `ToList`/`ToArray` unnecessarily, your LINQ code will perform a lot faster. Exposing `ICollection`/`IList` vs `IEnumerable` would not change the speed of your LINQ queries.

Comment: Thanks you guys really clarified some stuff for me :)

Comment: I am just going to use IList<Photo> instead.

Comment: @codingjoe You mean you're going to expose that as the property type? If so *bad idea*! That lets arbitrary code outside the class add or remove items from the list without your class knowing. (Unless you really don't care if that can happen.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson I was thinking going for oleksii's suggestion down below.

Comment: @codingjoe You changed your mind? I thought you were going for grrrrrrr's suggestion (that's the one I would use).

Comment: @MatthewWatson sorry English is not my first language...and I am currently doing a lot of stuff simultaneously... I dont get who grrrrrr is (hope I did not miss any remaining 'r' in it)?

Comment: @codingjoe It's the person who write the answer that you accepted to your question!

Comment: @MatthewWatson I see it...I should have searched for it on the page.
oleksii's solution seemed to be easier, as I used IEnumerable a lot of places and I just made them all to IList. Your concern is actually making me think a lot more about your (grrr's) suggestion. Let me think about the downside of using IList...

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable<T>` does not allow sequence to be changed during enumeration. There is no other way but use another interface, such `ICollection<T>` or `IList<T>`.

So that the `Photos` will look like

```
public IList<Photo> Photos { get; set;}
// or
public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set;}
```

You can of course use actual classes and not interfaces, but usually interfaces give you more freedom.

Comment: I read that using IEnumerable would make my LINQ perform lot faster. Would that change if I use another collection interface?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myAlbum.Photos = myAlbum.Photos.Concat(newPhoto);
```

You need to add `using System.Linq;` on top of your file.